# Sourcing Motors for larger robots

Tags: motor

I have been wanting to build larger robots and r/c cars for some time now, but one issue I have had is trying to find larger motors, in the range of electric wheelchair motor size. I found one set on ebay but I am trying to find a more reliable source for these.

To make my question more clear, I am looking for a reliable source(s) for medium size electric motors around the size and power rating of a typical electric wheelchair motor

Comment: Look at Baldor or Kollmorgen (to mention two options).

Comment: This totally depends on output torque and speed, duty cycle size limits. Transmissions can do a lot... Look at your requirements, than select a motor. Not select a motor and build your robot.

Answer (score 1):

From what I found doing a quick search on eBay for electric wheel chair motors, they output 100-150 watts nominal. This isn't that much power and can easily be found.

If you are looking for precision miniature drive high quality motors (that come with a certain price tag):

1. Maxon Motors
2. Faulhaber

If space isn't at a premium in your designs, you can expand your search to lower quality, bigger motors that are much less expensive. A quick eBay search got me the two follwing manufacturers:

1. Dunkermotoren
2. Groschopp

If you are looking for a distributor, I know of RobotShop.

You can probably find others with the help of eBay or Google.

Answer (score 0):

For small quantities and ad-hoc projects just above the eBay level: www.surpluscenter.com

For repeatable prototypes: www.robotmarketplace.com 
then track back by searching on manufacturer for larger quantities.